# How do you pipe scripts into NodeJs from command line?

Tags: node.js, shell, command-line

From command line, I'd like to take a script from my paste board (FYI: pbpaste is an OSX feature) and pipe it into the Node's repl command line tool.  For example:

`pbpaste | node -e`

This does not evaluate the contents in my clipboard.  How do I get the runtime to do this?

Comment: It should just work without the `-e`, I think.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `-e` option is for running JS passed as an argument. To run JS from stdin, you can simply pipe to `node` directly.

```
pbpaste | node
```

Comment: I can't get this to work for piping a downloaded script to node.  (i.e. "curl -L https://<myscipt> | node")

Comment: @ColeChamberlain Please post a new question.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to do the trick:

`node -e "$(pbpaste)"`

Comment: `node -e "process.stdout.write('hi');"`