# Node CLI tool evaluate string

Tags: node.js, bash, command-line-interface

Is there any way to evaluate a string of Javascript code using the NodeJS CLI tool?

For example, with Perl it would be `perl -e "code"`, with Python `python -c "code"`, with Ruby `ruby -e "code"`, and with PHP, `php -r "code"`.

Is there any flag with the NodeJS CLI tool to evaluate a string of code like this?

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14352725/how-do-you-pipe-scripts-into-nodejs-from-command-line), but it does not help since I am not asking how to pipe scripts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a way to do this. You can do it with the same flag that is used with Perl and Ruby: `-e`

```sh
node -e "code"
```